# Retrieve json values from IBM watson personality insights?

Tags: java, json, ibm-cloud, watson, personality-insights

I have integrated IBM watson into my java application. When I enter a string into the input and click on submit, it will return a json string.

I want to retrieve the ID, percentage and sampling error of all the data from the JSON output and print it to the console. My goal is to display these values via graphs etc but for now I would like to print it to the console.

The following shows an output of a JSON string from IBM...

```
{
  "id": "*UNKNOWN*",
  "processed_lang": "en",
  "source": "*UNKNOWN*",
  "tree": {
    "children": [

  {
    "children": [
      {
        "category": "personality",
        "children": [
          {
            "category": "personality",
            "children": [
              {
                "category": "personality",
                "id": "Adventurousness",
                "name": "Adventurousness",
                "percentage": 0.7576333190619886,
                "sampling_error": 0.0546254744
              },
              {
                "category": "personality",
                "id": "Artistic interests",
                "name": "Artistic interests",
                "percentage": 0.9961053555258998,
                "sampling_error": 0.1107314804
              },
              {
                "category": "personality",
                "id": "Emotionality",
                "name": "Emotionality",
                "percentage": 0.9969135057125771,
                "sampling_error": 0.0512783209
              },
              {
                "category": "personality",
                "id": "Imagination",
                "name": "Imagination",
                "percentage": 0.9999959208042641,
                "sampling_error": 0.0688620254
              },
              {
                "category": "personality",
                "id": "Intellect",
                "name": "Intellect",
                "percentage": 0.9994099673298837,
                "sampling_error": 0.0605583001
              },
              {
                "category": "personality",
                "id": "Liberalism",
                "name": "Authority-challenging",
                "percentage": 0.9994874479675643,
                "sampling_error": 0.0885760288
              }
            ],
            "id": "Openness",
            "name": "Openness",
            "percentage": 0.9737349754461915,
            "sampling_error": 0.0654457806
          },
          {
            "category": "personality",
            "children": [
              {
                "category": "personality",
                "id": "Achievement striving",
                "name": "Achievement striving",
                "percentage": 0.2084296846463588,
                "sampling_error": 0.1049539128
              },
              {
                "category": "personality",
                "id": "Cautiousness",
                "name": "Cautiousness",
                "percentage": 0.0037975029109792446,
                "sampling_error": 0.0970637329
              },
              {
                "category": "personality",
                "id": "Dutifulness",
                "name": "Dutifulness",
                "percentage": 0.07881209714217596,
                "sampling_error": 0.066306727
              },
              {
                "category": "personality",
                "id": "Orderliness",
                "name": "Orderliness",
                "percentage": 0.0077044305760685106,
                "sampling_error": 0.0746778463
              },
              {
                "category": "personality",
                "id": "Self-discipline",
                "name": "Self-discipline",
                "percentage": 1.437985270622555E-4,
                "sampling_error": 0.0503025256
              },
              {
                "category": "personality",
                "id": "Self-efficacy",
                "name": "Self-efficacy",
                "percentage": 0.38675464454076475,
                "sampling_error": 0.0979909516
              }
            ],
            "id": "Conscientiousness",
            "name": "Conscientiousness",
            "percentage": 0.001042729975404666,
            "sampling_error": 0.08176061570000001
          },
          {
            "category": "personality",
            "children": [
              {
                "category": "personality",
                "id": "Activity level",
                "name": "Activity level",
                "percentage": 0.6196452750702242,
                "sampling_error": 0.0832737804
              },
              {
                "category": "personality",
                "id": "Assertiveness",
                "name": "Assertiveness",
                "percentage": 0.26375499982159656,
                "sampling_error": 0.0886493817
              },
              {
                "category": "personality",
                "id": "Cheerfulness",
                "name": "Cheerfulness",
                "percentage": 0.10404848807697964,
                "sampling_error": 0.1113483353
              },
              {
                "category": "personality",
                "id": "Excitement-seeking",
                "name": "Excitement-seeking",
                "percentage": 0.984475526983271,
                "sampling_error": 0.0849837878
              },
              {
                "category": "personality",
                "id": "Friendliness",
                "name": "Outgoing",
                "percentage": 0.0997698590364568,
                "sampling_error": 0.08007498760000001
              },
              {
                "category": "personality",
                "id": "Gregariousness",
                "name": "Gregariousness",
                "percentage": 0.21721928079554653,
                "sampling_error": 0.0614148761
              }
            ],
            "id": "Extraversion",
            "name": "Extraversion",
            "percentage": 0.1191009678887297,
            "sampling_error": 0.0612391351
          },
          {
            "category": "personality",
            "children": [
              {
                "category": "personality",
                "id": "Altruism",
                "name": "Altruism",
                "percentage": 0.9663606952317318,
                "sampling_error": 0.0755869969
              },
              {
                "category": "personality",
                "id": "Cooperation",
                "name": "Cooperation",
                "percentage": 0.05636998991462855,
                "sampling_error": 0.0841720961
              },
              {
                "category": "personality",
                "id": "Modesty",
                "name": "Modesty",
                "percentage": 0.2979258338307789,
                "sampling_error": 0.0604476641
              },
              {
                "category": "personality",
                "id": "Morality",
                "name": "Uncompromising",
                "percentage": 0.23809655664417645,
                "sampling_error": 0.067167429
              },
              {
                "category": "personality",
                "id": "Sympathy",
                "name": "Sympathy",
                "percentage": 0.9995292854388587,
                "sampling_error": 0.1033760304
              },
              {
                "category": "personality",
                "id": "Trust",
                "name": "Trust",
                "percentage": 0.482389923327414,
                "sampling_error": 0.0617374794
              }
            ],
            "id": "Agreeableness",
            "name": "Agreeableness",
            "percentage": 0.020744291827208383,
            "sampling_error": 0.10207355
          },
          {
            "category": "personality",
            "children": [
              {
                "category": "personality",
                "id": "Anger",
                "name": "Fiery",
                "percentage": 0.8730389482839509,
                "sampling_error": 0.0995015107
              },
              {
                "category": "personality",
                "id": "Anxiety",
                "name": "Prone to worry",
                "percentage": 0.9843445923656408,
                "sampling_error": 0.0592009988
              },
              {
                "category": "personality",
                "id": "Depression",
                "name": "Melancholy",
                "percentage": 0.9977329242304231,
                "sampling_error": 0.0635185366
              },
              {
                "category": "personality",
                "id": "Immoderation",
                "name": "Immoderation",
                "percentage": 0.9844251835860516,
                "sampling_error": 0.057216091000000004
              },
              {
                "category": "personality",
                "id": "Self-consciousness",
                "name": "Self-consciousness",
                "percentage": 0.9212364705122658,
                "sampling_error": 0.0613118077
              },
              {
                "category": "personality",
                "id": "Vulnerability",
                "name": "Susceptible to stress",
                "percentage": 0.9754505231012063,
                "sampling_error": 0.0910170775
              }
            ],
            "id": "Neuroticism",
            "name": "Emotional range",
            "percentage": 0.016735992752090756,
            "sampling_error": 0.09667632949999999
          }
        ],
        "id": "Conscientiousness_parent",
        "name": "Conscientiousness",
        "percentage": 0.001042729975404666
      }
    ],
    "id": "personality",
    "name": "Big 5"
  },
  {
    "children": [
      {
        "category": "needs",
        "children": [
          {
            "category": "needs",
            "id": "Challenge",
            "name": "Challenge",
            "percentage": 0.03854668759096469,
            "sampling_error": 0.08792646900000001
          },
          {
            "category": "needs",
            "id": "Closeness",
            "name": "Closeness",
            "percentage": 0.11501071999168766,
            "sampling_error": 0.08673297320000001
          },
          {
            "category": "needs",
            "id": "Curiosity",
            "name": "Curiosity",
            "percentage": 0.7545746706702292,
            "sampling_error": 0.12524725080000002
          },
          {
            "category": "needs",
            "id": "Excitement",
            "name": "Excitement",
            "percentage": 0.5258169972550338,
            "sampling_error": 0.1145578396
          },
          {
            "category": "needs",
            "id": "Harmony",
            "name": "Harmony",
            "percentage": 0.20932625096475815,
            "sampling_error": 0.11486202649999999
          },
          {
            "category": "needs",
            "id": "Ideal",
            "name": "Ideal",
            "percentage": 0.1024721838723201,
            "sampling_error": 0.1040952874
          },
          {
            "category": "needs",
            "id": "Liberty",
            "name": "Liberty",
            "percentage": 0.20202017178331372,
            "sampling_error": 0.1511666568
          },
          {
            "category": "needs",
            "id": "Love",
            "name": "Love",
            "percentage": 0.3061638103614429,
            "sampling_error": 0.1056569794
          },
          {
            "category": "needs",
            "id": "Practicality",
            "name": "Practicality",
            "percentage": 0.27222283787496954,
            "sampling_error": 0.0920142043
          },
          {
            "category": "needs",
            "id": "Self-expression",
            "name": "Self-expression",
            "percentage": 0.4639718943621007,
            "sampling_error": 0.0854424349
          },
          {
            "category": "needs",
            "id": "Stability",
            "name": "Stability",
            "percentage": 0.003413184470600239,
            "sampling_error": 0.1117462741
          },
          {
            "category": "needs",
            "id": "Structure",
            "name": "Structure",
            "percentage": 0.08844897107940608,
            "sampling_error": 0.0840415393
          }
        ],
        "id": "Stability_parent",
        "name": "Stability",
        "percentage": 0.003413184470600239
      }
    ],
    "id": "needs",
    "name": "Needs"
  },
  {
    "children": [
      {
        "category": "values",
        "children": [
          {
            "category": "values",
            "id": "Conservation",
            "name": "Conservation",
            "percentage": 0.0023789880748844028,
            "sampling_error": 0.0714114533
          },
          {
            "category": "values",
            "id": "Openness to change",
            "name": "Openness to change",
            "percentage": 0.9530706270939822,
            "sampling_error": 0.0689225
          },
          {
            "category": "values",
            "id": "Hedonism",
            "name": "Hedonism",
            "percentage": 0.4245648852905599,
            "sampling_error": 0.14301226290000002
          },
          {
            "category": "values",
            "id": "Self-enhancement",
            "name": "Self-enhancement",
            "percentage": 0.1393112402607365,
            "sampling_error": 0.1088382406
          },
          {
            "category": "values",
            "id": "Self-transcendence",
            "name": "Self-transcendence",
            "percentage": 0.916055096052063,
            "sampling_error": 0.086876041
          }
        ],
        "id": "Conservation_parent",
        "name": "Conservation",
        "percentage": 0.0023789880748844028
      }
    ],
    "id": "values",
    "name": "Values"
  }
],
"id": "r",
"name": "root"
```

},
  "word_count": 133,
  "word_count_message": "There were 133 words in the input. We need a minimum of 600, preferably 1,200 or more, to compute statistically significant estimates"
}

Comment: Where are you actually stuck?

Comment: I want to get the values from the json string above. For example category, id, name and percentage. I want to first print it to the console then later convert it to graphs. @nitind